# about iphone development/deployment certificate

Tags: iphone, deployment, certificate

i wonder how many certificatation types for iphone development/deployment. i have heard there is an enterprice certificate. with that certificate you can build your app store for your corporate/firm and you can have chance to configure iphones which are in your app store, intstall programs etc...

are all right???

and i could not found any offical document about that, is there any link?

thansk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Apple Developer portal for iOS is [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/). There is a page specific to the enterprise developer program [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

Comment: yeah i see but i need much more info. there is not at http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: What kind of information, specifically? It's going to be hard to answer you without a more direct, specific question. The answer to the questions you asked is there (basically "yes"). What else do you need?

Comment: how can install/uninstall apps from any phone remotely? how can i configure any iphone device like changing settings, etc... via this enterpise certificate?

Answer (score 0):

There is information on [Apple's iOS Enterprise Program and iPhone Configuration Utility here](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/).  Included on that page is information on Enterprise app deployment.

Your company needs a corporate DUNS number in order to be eligible for this program.  $299 annual fee.

Comment: to distribute my application in corporate what do i need? do i need a web server so i deploy iphone application? how colleagues can access the application to install on their iphones? where can i register all corporate device udid? etc...